# TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, dart

Me está dando el error

> TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String')

He buscado en varios sitios pero las soluciones no se adaptan a la solución necesaria. Le he dado mil vueltas y no soy capaz de transformar el listado de noticias `List<dynamic>` en un map. Recibo el json de la api, pero no soy capaz de mapearlo.

**Mi modelo**
Este es el modelo que corresponde a un modelo en django, y hace referencia a un post de un blog, una noticia

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class ArticlesBlogResponse {
    ArticlesBlogResponse({
        required this.title,
        required this.content,
        required this.published,
        required this.image,
        required this.author,
        required this.categories,
        required this.status,
    });

    String title;
    String content;
    String published;
    String image;
    int author;
    List<int> categories;
    String status;

    factory ArticlesBlogResponse.fromJson(String str)   => ArticlesBlogResponse.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    //String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory ArticlesBlogResponse.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ArticlesBlogResponse(
        title: json["title"],
        content: json["content"],
        published: (json["published"]),
        image: json["image"],
        author: json["author"],
        categories: List<int>.from(json["categories"].map((x) => x)),
        //categories: json["categories"],
        status: json["status"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "title": title,
        "content": content,
        //"published": published.toIso8601String(),
        "published": published,
        "image": image,
        "author": author,
        "categories": List<dynamic>.from(categories.map((x) => x)),
        //"categories":categories,
        "status": status,
    };
}
```

**Mi función**
Este es el provider que utilizo para obtener el mapeo de las noticias del blog

```dart
class ArticlesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _baseUrl = 'pythonanywhere.com';

  List<ArticlesBlogResponse> article = [];

  ArticlesProvider() {
    print('ArticlesProvider Inicializado');

    this.getOnDisplayArticles();
  }

  getOnDisplayArticles() async {
    var url = Uri.https(_baseUrl, '/api/blog', {});
    final response = await http.get(
      url,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //final articlesResponse = ArticlesBlogResponse.fromJson(response.body);
      final articlesResponse = ArticlesBlogResponse.fromJson(json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))); 
      return articlesResponse;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      throw Exception('No es posible cargar el blog');
    }
  }
}
```

**Esto devuelve la api**

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Ley Orgánica 2/2022: los hijos de las mujeres víctimas de violencia de género podrán instar la liquidación del régimen matrimonial",
        "content": "<p>El BOE de este martes recoge la&nbsp;<a href=\"https://noticias.juridicas.com/base_datos/Fiscal/722583-lo-2-2022-de-21-mar-mejora-de-la-proteccion-de-las-personas-huerfanas-victimas.html\" target=\"_blank\">Ley Org&aacute;nica 2/2022, de 21 de marzo</a>,&nbsp;que establece&nbsp;diversas medidas de mejora de la protecci&oacute;n de las personas hu&eacute;rfanas v&iacute;ctimas de la violencia de g&eacute;nero. Adem&aacute;s de otras en el &aacute;mbito fiscal y en el de las prestaciones de la Seguridad Social, el texto trata de hacer frente a la i<strong>ncertidumbre sobre el procedimiento aplicable a la liquidaci&oacute;n de la sociedad de gananciales.</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<p>La nueva ley parte de la constataci&oacute;n de que la incertidumbre sobre el procedimiento aplicable a la liquidaci&oacute;n de la sociedad de gananciales en los casos de mujeres v&iacute;ctimas mortales de la violencia de g&eacute;nero y, en particular, la imposibilidad de acceder en algunos casos al r&eacute;gimen previsto en los&nbsp;<a href=\"https://noticias.juridicas.com/base_datos/Privado/l1-2000.l4t2.html#a806\" target=\"_blank\">art&iacute;culos 806 y siguientes de la Ley de Enjuiciamiento Civil</a>, est&aacute; perjudicando a las hu&eacute;rfanas y hu&eacute;rfanos que se encuentran en esta situaci&oacute;n, pues est&aacute; retrasando que puedan acceder a la liquidaci&oacute;n del r&eacute;gimen matrimonial de sus madres y, con ello, a la determinaci&oacute;n de su herencia, sin el acuerdo de los asesinos de aquellas, con las consecuencias negativas que de ello se derivan.</p>\r\n\r\n<h2>Legitimaci&oacute;n de los herederos</h2>\r\n\r\n<p>Con este prop&oacute;sito y para unificar los pronunciamientos judiciales en la materia, el nuevo texto reforma el r&eacute;gimen previsto en los art&iacute;culos 807 y siguientes de la LEC para regular expresamente la legitimaci&oacute;n de los herederos de la v&iacute;ctima fallecida para instar la liquidaci&oacute;n del r&eacute;gimen matrimonial.</p>",
        "published": "2022-04-08T03:03:39+02:00",
        "image": "/media/blog/noticia2.jpg",
        "author": 29,
        "categories": [
            1
        ],
        "status": "published"
    },
    {
       
    }
]
```

**Esta línea da el error**

[image: Descripción del error]

Comment: estás haciendo 2 decodes json.decode(utf8.decode , usa solo el utf8,decode

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir tu objeton `JSON` a `List`, obtienes su Map de esa lista y agregas cada elemento a una `List`, esto te puede funcionar

```
 roles:  (json['roles'] as List).map((e) =>  e as String).toList(),
```